# Compress folders older than x days

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, compression

In `/opt/abc` I have a path where a new folder gets created daily. In that folder a series of files gets created.

I would like to run a script every Sunday at 02:00 and compress each folder which is older than 2 days.
I would not like to have everything compressed to one folder, but each folder to get compressed individually. If the compression is successful, then the original folder can be deleted.

I have tried to create a script but all it does is to compress them to a single file. also it does not delete the original folders.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1):

This single command should do the job, so it can simply be entered into your crontab:

```
find /opt/abc/* -maxdepth 0 -mtime +2 ! -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar czf {}.tar.gz {} \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I haven't tested it that thoroughly, but I am sure it won't accidentally delete stuff.

It will, however, delete archives, if they have the same name as a directory in question before the `.tar.gz`, as GNU tar will overwrite, if the creation switch, `c`, is given. It will be safer if you archive into another directory:

```
find /opt/abc/* -maxdepth 0 -mtime +2 ! -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar czf /opt/abcompressed/{}.tar.gz {} \; -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Also, the archives will contain the directory structure `/opt/abc/<dirname>/<files>`, which I wasn't able to work around yet.

Comment: You can always strip unwanted parts of a tar archive when extracting using the `--strip-components` option, set the option's argument as 2, and it will remove the `/opt/abc/` part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) -n 1 to only pipe a single file argument into the [compress](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/compress/) command.

Be careful about spaces.

Comment: really helpful. how can i make it a whole script to run at once please?

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/directory -mtime +2 -exec ls "{}" \;
```

Is a useful snippet to list files over 2 days old, though it only counts full days, and there's an element of rounding that happens there, so using minutes with the `-mmin` option may work better. I've also seen people relpace the `-exec` with `print0` and pipe the output to `xargs`, handles unusual filenames better than `echo` would. You can specify the type of file `find` is looking for too, to make it only find directories, I think this is the `-type` option

You can replace the `ls` in the command with other commands, I often use ls to make sure I'm happy with the output, then replace it with `mv /path/to/target` when I'm removing files over a certain age. I suppose you could use a `tar` command in place of the `ls` to achieve the compression you want.

You could script this, and call the script as a `cron` job, `cron` is the script scheduler on Ubuntu (and other linux systems).

That should start you off!