# What's the missing argument to -exec?

Tags: command-line, bash, find, syntax

I use the following command to clear a directory, of files and directories over 30 days old, and move them to an archive directory which I can delete after a few weeks if nobody asks for their files back. The target directory has subdirectories by user name, so will the archive directory.

This is the command I use:

```
find /path/to/directory/username/ -mtime +30 -exec mv "{}" /path/to/archive/username/ \;
```

I suggested a modified version of this to answer a question on ask ubuntu, another user edited the code to change the end of line `\;` for `+` as it's faster(and more correct?). [See here](https://askubuntu.com/a/587276/320386)

However, using `+` in this way works if the `-exec` command is `ls -lh` but not in the actual command that I use. If I try it with `+` I get an error message:

```
find: missing argument to '-exec'
```

I don't understand why it's behaving this way, or what the correct command would be. Please don't just post a command correction, I'd like to understand rather than just follow a suggestion blindly.

Comment: Are you referring to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/644032/178596)? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26439638)might explain why

Comment: Thanks @Wilf I've updated to show which answer the edit happened on. The link you provided, has a further link which explains it in a manner that my brain can cope with.

Comment: Look at [What is the difference between using '+' and '\;' in -exec command?](http://askubuntu.com/a/558819/127327)

Comment: Thanks @souravc in a brilliantly cyclic manner that question is by the user that edited my command! Finally I get it `+` supplies multiple arguments to the same command, but `mv` can't cope with that!

Comment: @Arronical mv can, see my answer^^

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The user in that post may said that the `+` sign at the end of a `-exec` command is faster, but not why.

Lets assume the `find` command return the following files:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
/path/to/file3
```

The normal `-exec` command (`-exec command {} \;`) runs once for each matching file. For example:

```
find ... -exec mv {} /target/ \;
```

Executes:

```
mv /path/to/file1 /target/
mv /path/to/file2 /target/
mv /path/to/file3 /target/
```

If you use the `+` sign (`-exec command {} +`) the command is build by adding multiple matched files at the end of the command. For example:

```
find ... -exec mv -t /target/ {} +
```

Executes:

```
mv -t /target/ /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3
```

To use the `+` flag correctly the argument to process must be at the end of the command, not in the middle. That's why `find` trows `missing argument to '-exec'` in your example; it misses the closing `{}`.

Comment: I've always wondered why `find -exec` requires the `{}` to be the last arg, when used with `+`.  Anyone know why that design decision was made, instead of letting constructs like the OP's command line work?

Answer (score 11):

The user explained their edit....

[image: '+' exec's terminator is faster than '\;' see https://askubuntu.com/questions/558817/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-exec-command; and creating a backup file from original file is good idea]

...using [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558817/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-exec-command). I think basically instead of using multiple commands, it sends all the filenames to one command instance, to speed things up. Here is a example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085156/using-semicolon-vs-plus-with-exec-in-find):

> Using -exec with a semicolon (`find . -exec ls '{}' \;`), will execute
>
> ```
> ls file1
> ls file2
> ls file3
> ```
>
> But if you use a plus sign instead (`find . -exec ls '{}' \+`), all
>   filenames will be passed as arguments to a single command:
>
> ```
> ls file1 file2 file3
> ```

There are other forms available using `;` and `+` as well (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26439638/2943276):)

Therefore the following example syntax is allowed for find command:

> ```
> find . -exec echo {} \;
> find . -exec echo {} ';'
> find . -exec echo {} ";"
> find . -exec echo {} \+
> find . -exec echo {} +
> ```

HOWEVER, I'm not sure this will work with the move command anyway, as it's syntax is  `mv [OPTION]... SOURCE DEST`, unless the `-t` option or similar is used. However it should work with `ls` with no extra options etc as they can understand when multiple filenames are given. The `+` may also need to be escaped (i.e. `\+`)

Comment: Both great answers, but I've got to give it to chaos for being a tiny bit quicker, and explaining the `mv -t`, both +1s though!